# TypeError: Cannot set property '<value>' of null

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function in my controller. I'm hard coding the values before calling the service as you can see below. It throws `TypeError: Cannot set property 'mag_id' of null at r.$scope.subscribeToMag` on the first line.

It's not even going up to the service call, all help is appreciated. If I don't instantiate the variable to null it throws a different error.

```
$scope.newSubscription=null;

$scope.subscribeToMag = function(){
    $scope.newSubscription.mag_id = 2;
    $scope.newSubscription.user_id = 6;
    $scope.newSubscription.status = "E";
    $scope.newSubscription.end_date = "2016-02-19"    

    hobbyService.subscribeMag($scope.newSubscription)
        .then(
            function(response){
                $scope.subscribeResult=response;
                console.log($scope.subscribeResult);
            },
            function(err){
                console.log('error subscribing to the mag: ', err);
            }                 
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're instantiating `$scope.newSubscription` as `null`, but in your function you treat it as an object:

```
$scope.newSubscription.mag_id
```

If you change your code to this it should work:

```
$scope.newSubscription = {};
```

Comment: elsewhere, i am instantiating to null and setting values using ng-model in html and when i call the function, the form input is in model elements and that doesn't throw this same error. ex:                     <div>
                        <label class="w3-label w3-text-black"><B>Status</B></label>  
                        <input type="text" class="w3-input" id="name" ng-model="newSubscription.status">
                      </div>

Comment: Please make a new question and I'll try to help again